# Does semphore in net5.0 support global semaphores and how does security work?

Tags: c#, .net, semaphore, .net-5

.net 5.0 doesn't have the semaphore security class (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.semaphoresecurity?view=windowsdesktop-5.0), and the constructor doesn't have access controls.  Does this mean that anyone can close my semaphore (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphore?view=net-5.0), or that global semaphores don't work anymore?

Comment: What exactly stops you from trying it? Spoiler: there's no security breach there.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?
You do have the global semaphore (not SemaphoreSlim):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphore?view=net-5.0

It accepts a string which represents its name in the system

Comment: It's a huge problem and it is a security breach. IMO, they broke it in .NET 5 by failing to create a constructor -- just as the OP mentioned -- that accepts a SemaphoreSecurity object like the one in .NET Framework had. Same issue with Mutex class. These unfinished APIs are much harder to use in .NET Core vs .NET Framework. The originals were simple, you could construct a Semaphore and pass an enum value for the security. Now, you have to call a separate method with a factory method that accepts some 'mask' integer that's not documented. Useless.

Comment: Their own docs say this is a risk: 

"Use access control security to protect a Semaphore object that represents a named semaphore, preferably by using a constructor that specifies a System.Security.AccessControl.SemaphoreSecurity object. You can also apply access control security using the Semaphore.SetAccessControl method, *but this leaves a window of vulnerability between the time the semaphore is created and the time it is protected.*"

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/semaphore-and-semaphoreslim#named-semaphores

Comment: The writers of .NET Framework were brilliant. This .NET Core stuff, not so much. A lot was lost in the reorganization.